# Python: sum adjacent numbers with same sign in a list

Tags: python, list, sum

I have to sum adjacent numbers in a list like this:

`ls = [5, -2, -2, 2, -4, -2 ,-2, 7, 3, 1]`

The output should be: `[5, -4, 2, -8, 11]`

Comment: I have to find the fastest way possible to solve it

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
from itertools import groupby

ls = [5, -2, -2, 2, -4, -2 ,-2, 7, 3, 1]

[sum(g) for _, g in groupby(ls, key=lambda x: x < 0)]
# [5, -4, 2, -8, 11]
```

Comment: I was gonna expand mine with the comprehension, but here it is! good answer!

Comment: how much it is efficient ? btw ty

Comment: @francescociao This is very efficient. Both groupby and and its groups are lazy iterators, no intermediate lists are created in memory. `sum` is implemented and optimized in C as well as the comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.gropby`, grouping by less than 0:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: sum(x[1]), itertools.groupby(ls, key=lambda x: x<=0)))
[5, -4, 2, -8, 11]
```

Comment: how much it is efficient ? btw ty

Comment: @francescociao, it is really efficient, as well as the other answer. You can use both, they can be even a bit better getting rid of the lambda functions ;)